# Use a date in a table and compare it to a new one

Tags: php, drupal-8

I have a date that is automatically generate when someone enter a code on the website of the day he did it.
If his offer expired, he can still make it extends within the 6months after the expiration, and that's what I'm trying to do, is to get the date when he entered the code, to compare if it's been more than 6months, if yes then i throw an error message otherwise I validate and he is redirect to another page.
I also want to check if code has expired, if it didn't then he can't extend it.

I tried severals things but I'm new on php/drupal8 so it didn't work as expected

How i call my function :

```
$values = $form_state->getValues();
$dateExpi = \Drupal::service('lsb_coffret.manager')->expirer($values['dateActivation']);
```

Here is the function, I know it's not good and I also think i might need to add my code in the fields to check

```
public function expirer($dateActivation)
  {
    $dateExpi = new \DateTime();
    $dateExpi->modify('+1,5 Year');
    $dateExpi->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $result = $this->connection->select('lsb_code','lc')
      ->fields('lc')
      ->condition('dateActivation',$dateActivation)
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll();


    if ($result > $dateExpi){
      alert('You can\' extend your offer cause it\'s been more than 6months since it expired.');
    }
  }
```

Thank you for your help, I think what i ask is pretty easy to make but I just don't know where to start